# Duplicating a product with Code in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to write a custom module which is capable of duplicating a product into multiple products with only varying SKU. I have tried using `function duplicate()` under /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php in my custom module. But its not working.

I am using the below code in my custom Obesrever.php file to duplicate, but duplication is not occuring

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$newProduct = $product->duplicate();
```

can anyone suggest me any links to do this or any code format would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please define "not working" more precisely.

Comment: I have briefed it out in my question.. Please have a look

Comment: Have you already proven that your custom observer really is being called? If so, what does `$newProduct` contain? Is it `null` or an instance of `Mage_Sales_Catalog_Product`? If it's `null`, check your `exception.log`.

Comment: Yes.. i can confirm that my custom observer is called. I checked it by printing a text and exiting out of the observer.
I just found this code ($product->duplicate()) under duplicateAction() in productController and thought it would help me to duplicate a product and used it. But no use of it..

not sure what i am missing in the code

Comment: The `duplicate()` method should work (used it myself several times). My guess would be, that `duplicate()` is raising an exception, which you are not aware of. Check what type of data `$newProduct` contains. Is it `null`, or an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` (wrote the class name wrong in my previous comment, sorry)?

Comment: ts ok.. i will check whether the variable $newProduct is null or not.. i actually put an exit after calling duplicate() function in Observer.php file. Will this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can post the complete function that you are trying to debug or create duplicate products and config.xml (where you are trying to call the event).

Below code works for me in CE 1.9.2.2 without any problems. This function does the following tasks:

> 1. Creates duplicate of the original product
> 2. Sets the stock to "In Stock" and Qty to "100" (hard coded for now)
> 3. Automates reindexing

```
public function indexAction() //change the function name
{
    $productId      = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

    $productObject  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');    
    $_product       = $productObject->load($productId);

    $newProduct     = $_product->duplicate();

    //new product status is disabled - to view in the frontend you will need to set the status as enabled
    $newProduct->setStatus(1);
    $newProduct->setName('Duplicate-' . $_product->getName());
    $newProduct->setSku('value-' . $productId);
    $newProduct->setWebsiteIds($_product->getWebsiteIds());

    //set the product stock and qty to display product in the frontend
    //while creating duplicate product, it will update the new product to have qty 0 and out of stock
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($newProduct->getId());
    if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 && $stockItem->getManageStock())
    {
        $qty = 100;
        $stockItem->setQty($qty);
        $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
        $stockItem->save();
    }

    $newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);

    //automate reindexing - to display the product in the frontend
    $indexers = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
    foreach ($indexers as $indexer)
    {
        $indexer->reindexEverything();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding...